# How to block user from copying files? C++ / C#

Tags: c#, c++, file, block, copying

I need to block user from copying files from districted directory or which size is for example over 50 MB. I've found ICoopyHook but that's for folders only. Do you know anything like this but for files?

Comment: Classic XY question.  Don't create files bigger than 50 MB.

Comment: I don't want to block creating files over 50MB, i want to block copying them.